# concatenation code column not found in a table using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with few columns and I am trying to concatenate the code column with rank. But it throws me an error by saying code not found, this is in the concatenation I am doing with rank and code. The code column is a calculated column as you can see from the query. Could anyone please point me where I am doing a mistake?

```
table mm
ID     cal_dtm     rank    milestone_hier_onb    tr
CNT    1/31/2020   1       RFR                   EEZ

table dd

ID  frs            lst           frst       lst_s               cal
CNT 6/20/2018      6/28/2018                6/28/2018         1/31/2020
```

Query

```
 WITH r
    AS (
        SELECT dd.ID,
            dd.frs,
            dd.lst,
            dd.frst,
            dd.lst_s,
            dd.cal_dtm,
            mm.tr,
            mm.ipf_rank,
            mm.milestone_hier_onb
        FROM dos dd
        LEFT JOIN plw mm ON dd.ID = mm.ID
            AND dd.cal_dtm = mm.cal_dtm
        )
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT r.ID,
            r.cal_dtm,
            'lp' AS code,
            r.lst_s AS planned,
            r.lst AS actual,
            r.tr,
            r.ipf_rank AS rank,
            r.milestone_hier_onb AS onb,
            * * CONCAT (
                r.ipf_rank,
                code
                ) AS milestone_label * *
        FROM r
        WHERE r.lst IS NOT NULL
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT r.ID,
            r.cal_dtm,
            'fp' AS code,
            r.frst AS planned,
            r.frs AS actual,
            r.tr,
            r.ipf_rank AS rank,
            r.milestone_hier_onb AS onb,
            * * CONCAT (
                r.ipf_rank,
                code
                ) AS milestone_label * *
        FROM r
        WHERE r.frs IS NOT NULL
        )
    ORDER BY ID,
        cal_dtm,
        code
```

Expected output

```
ID  Cal             code          pl            Al       tr     milestone_label       rank   onb 
CNT 1/31/2020       lp        6/28/2018   6/28/2018             lp 1                   1
CNT 1/31/2020       fp                    6/20/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `CODE` like that; it is a constant so - concatenate that constant, e.g.

```
... 'lp' as code,
    r.ipf_rank || 'lp' as milestone_label
...
```

---

How to add space?

```
r.ipf_rank ||' '|| 'lp' as milestone_label

or

r.ipf_rank ||' lp' as milestone_label
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to add space between these concat?

Comment: Sure. Add it as a separate string (1st example), or simply add it in front of LP. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let try:

1. remove order by
2. add alias **concat( r.ipf_rank, code) => **concat( r.ipf_rank, r.code)

Comment: if i remove order by the idea of order by on ID and cal_dtm will be gone

Comment: So you remove order by then resolved the issue or not?

Comment: You are not getting the point, i can not remove the order by. I have a reason why I have it. But, in any case thanks for your answer